# 'HTTP ERROR 404 NOT Found' error when accessing 'localhost:8983/solr/ckan'

Tags: solr, ckan

The connection to 'localhost:8983/solr' is successful.

However, when I access 'localhost:8983/solr/ckan',

I get 'HTTP ERROR 404 NOT Found' error.
How can I solve this problem?

The solr version is 8.11.2

[image]